# Foreign key BIGSERIAL NULL Postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, hibernate

I can not insert a record in the POSTGRES database, I want the foreign key to be null.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE sad_avaliado (
    id                BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    tenant_id         INT8 NOT NULL,
    funcionario_id    BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    epoca_id          BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    cca_id            BIGSERIAL,
    avaliador_id      BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    apagado           boolean NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
alter table sad_avaliado add constraint sad_funcionario_fkey foreign key (funcionario_id) references sad_funcionario;
alter table sad_avaliado add constraint sad_epoca_fkey foreign key (epoca_id) references sad_epoca;
alter table sad_avaliado add constraint sad_cca_fkey foreign key (cca_id) references sad_cca;
alter table sad_avaliado add constraint sad_avaliador_fkey foreign key (avaliador_id) references sad_avaliador;
```

My SQL Insert:

```
INSERT INTO public.sad_avaliado(
id, tenant_id, funcionario_id, epoca_id, cca_id, avaliador_id, apagado)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, null, 1, false);
```

My Error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "cca_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: You should only ever use one \[big]serial per table. Make the fields int8, drop the default, drop the sequences. Also the column might have `not null` as the default, because it's bigserial. Check with `\d sad_avaliado`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The foreign key references for `BIGSERIAL` should use `BIGINT`:

```
CREATE TABLE sad_avaliado (
    id                BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    tenant_id         INT8 NOT NULL,
    funcionario_id    BIGINT NOT NULL,
    epoca_id          BIGINT NOT NULL,
    cca_id            BIGINT,
    avaliador_id      BIGINT NOT NULL,
    apagado           boolean NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
```

I think this is the one exception to the notion that foreign key references should have the same type as the primary key.  I mean, the underlying type *is the same*, but `BIGSERIAL` is used to specify that it is auto-incrementing (other databases use a separate keyword such as `auto_increment` or `identity`).

Comment: This was really helpful :-) I actually was creating a table and wondered why some of my columns are automatically set to required and have a sequence in their definition as "column_default". I have not thought about "bigserial" actually being like a wrapper for "bigint" that ads incrementation; I guess maybe the fact that I mainly used Oracle databases kind of explains me?

Answer (score 2):

bigserial is meant for autoincremented id columns and it has default "not null" and creates one sequence.

And you should not specify your id in insert statements as it is inserted as default with nextval()

see this example

```
    test=# create table test01 ( id bigserial );
    CREATE TABLE
    test=# \d test01*
                                Table "public.test01"
     Column |  Type  | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
    --------+--------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
     id     | bigint |           | not null | nextval('test01_id_seq'::regclass)

                           Sequence "public.test01_id_seq"
      Type  | Start | Minimum |       Maximum       | Increment | Cycles? | Cache 
    --------+-------+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------+-------
     bigint |     1 |       1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 | no      |     1
    Owned by: public.test01.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bigint` instead of `bigserial`.